# Убрать сжатие текста android

Tags: android, html, html5

Привет всем, обычно зачастую браузер в Android сжимает текст под экран.

Можно ли как-то это избежать при создании HTML страницы?

Answer (score 1):

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
device-width - ширина монитора, с этим мета тегом в head телефон делает то, о чём вы говорите. Укажите этот параметр в числовое значение, чтоб андроид этого не делал.
Вы ведь об этом?

Comment: Да, спасибо.